# Android app crash after trying to load data to listview

Tags: java, android

after alot of trying and a little knowledge about android programmming i want to get data from my database but my app crashes everything i call my function "populateDrinkerslijst"

this is my mainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private ListView mListView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drinkers_lijst);

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    populateDrinkersLijst()


}

public void populateDrinkersLijst() {
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getDrinkers();

    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    listData.add("test");

    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new home_fragment(), "Home");
    adapter.addFragment(new scan_pintje(), "scan pintje");
    adapter.addFragment(new controleer_pintje(), "controle pintje");
    adapter.addFragment(new beste_zuiper(), "beste drinkers");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

this is my database class :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "pintjes_table";
private static final String COL1 = "ID";
private static final String COL2 = "name";
private static final String COL3 = "barcode";



public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 + " TEXT, " + COL3 + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME );
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String naam,String barcode) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2,naam);
    contentValues.put(COL3,barcode);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getDrinkers(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    //String query = "SELECT " + COL2 + ",count(" + COL2 + ") AS aantal FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " GROUP BY " + COL2 + " ORDER BY aantal DESC";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;

}
```

and it keeps crashing here :

```
ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    listData.add(1, "test");

    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
    }
```

EDIT :

Got this error after debugging :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: What are the logged errors ? you have forgot to close the cursor at the end of you method

Comment: I think you need to check cursor is not null and also call cursor.moveToFirst before iterating on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Added `null` checking to cursor `data` before getting `value` from it.

**2.** Add string to list using `listData.add("test")` instead of `listData.add(1, "test")`.

**3.** Make sure your `layout` contains ListView `drinkers_lijst` and use `ArrayAdapter<String>` instead of `ListAdapter<String>`.

**Update method `populateDrinkersLijst()` as below:**

```
public void populateDrinkersLijst() {

    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getDrinkers();

    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    listData.add("test");

    // Check weather cursor is empty
    if(data.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            listData.add(data.getString(1));

        }while(data.moveToNext());
    }

    // Close cursor  
    data.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As you are using `ViewPager` with multiple `Fragments`. You should initialize `views` for fragments from your `Fragment` classes.

Move `ListView` related code to your fragment `beste_zuiper`. Update `MainActivity` and `beste_zuiper` class as below:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new home_fragment(), "Home");
        mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new scan_pintje(), "scan pintje");
        mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new controleer_pintje(), "controle pintje");
        mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new beste_zuiper(), "beste drinkers");
        viewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPageAdapter);
    }
}
```

**beste_zuiper.java:**

```
public class beste_zuiper extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "bestezuiperfragment";


    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private ListView mListView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beste_zuiper_fragment, container, false);

        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drinkers_lijst);

        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        populateDrinkersLijst();

        return view;
    }

    public void populateDrinkersLijst() {

        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getDrinkers();

        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        listData.add("test");

        // Check weather cursor is empty
        if(data.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                listData.add(data.getString(1));

            }while(data.moveToNext());
        }

        // Close cursor
        data.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Hope this will work~

Comment: don't forget to close the cursor ;)

Comment: Added this code , still didn't work , now i tried debugging and added error at my main post!

Comment: Make sure your layout contains listView `drinkers_lijst`and use adapter as >> `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);`

Comment: i used the adapter as you said , but still my mlistview seems null or empty. does it matter that my listview i want to fill is in another fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You declared listData by 

`ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();`

listData is an arraylist not a HashMap.
 You cannot add key values to an ArrayList.

```
listData.add(1, "test");   //this is not correct
```

You can only add strings

```
listData.add("test");      //this is correct
```

Comment: this should have been deleted already ! i knew this was wrong

Comment: It's nothing to do with HashMap...He used overloaded method [add(int index, E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)).
The crash is because `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have used  [ArrayList.add(int index, E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)). And your code are throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception as you trying to insert value at position `1` into empty list. The simplest fix is just start from `0`. But usually you don't care about element position you just want to append value to the list. So simply use [ArrayList.add(E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) method instead.